# How to make a object jump and come back down to the where it began?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing a game, but can't seem to make my guy collide with an object to end his jump and bring him back down to the ground and to make an object the ground so that the "guy" doesn't fall out of the screen.

--- I don't need any animation, the guy has already been animated, just need collision coding---

Comment: When is `guyMoving` being called and how? Have you considered using SpriteKit? Also take a look at animations, there are many good tutorials, i.e. : http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation

Comment: I am not so familiar with SpriteKit , I just started fully understanding Objective-C. I have the animations, i just need to set limits on how high the object can jump and then to return to where it began. @Losiowaty

Answer (score 0):

What you shown in your code is only half of what you need. You react to users touch by setting the variable, but you didn't show how you call your `guyMoving` method which seems to be responsible for actually changing its position on screen. This can be of course done, but would be really cumbersome.

The easiest way to achieve what you want would be to use UIViewAnimations ( longer tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation) - same link as in my comment ) :

```
CGPoint startPoint = guy.center;
CGPoint endPoint = guy.center;
endPoint.y -= 100;

[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    guy.center = endPoint;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations^{
            guy.center = startPoint;
        };
    }];
}];
```

Put this in your `touchesBegan` method. It will play two animations, one after the other : the first one will move the `guy` a 100 pixels upwards in 5 seconds, and when it finishes, it will launch another animation with same duration and move the `guy` downwards.

Note : there are better ways to chain longer animations. You should laso take a look at [UIView docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) chapter about Animations.

Comment: Thanks, I and may I ask how you learned to code in Objective-C @Losiowaty

Comment: A lot of Google'ing, StackOverflow'ing and help from more experienced friend :) There are many great resources out there ( i.e. the site with the tutorial I linked has a lot of really great tutorials, some targeting games too ), the Apple docs are quite good. Also this site : http://objc.io, has great articles, though some of them are a little more advanced.

Comment: This game I am developing just needs a few tweeks and should be ready to launch, I just don't know how to use Spritebuilder to my advantage :/ @Losiowaty

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you like skype or something ? @Losiowaty

Comment: At the moment no, I may be avaiable to chat in 10 hours after work, but you'd need 9 more rep. to use SO chat. If you have a specific problem post a question and if not me, than someone will surely guide you to solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that whatever you want to do can be easily done by the use of UIAnimation, more specifically, by introducing gravity and collisions.

Take a look at apple's documentation and i hope that helps you

Comment: That's exactly what I want to implement, collision with another object so that the "guy" can't continue jumping, and then when it lands on the ground he can continue to run until you tap to jump over another object. @Light Yahgami it's just that I am not a expert at coding Objective-C.

Comment: I am providing you a link to a tutorial, read it and i guess it will work for u. 
http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/ios-7-uikit-dynamics-gravity-and-collisions.html

Comment: And if the answered helped please tick it as answered, it might help further people who has the same problem